# MonoTouch RedLaser SDK Object

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to use the RedLaser SDK 3.30 with MonoTouch. Here is the code I am using:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/RedLaser

When I click the thunderbolt button to scan a barcode, my app crashes on my iPod touch. I am using ARM7. Here is my crash log:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
0   RedLaserSample                      0x01669015 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
1   RedLaserSample                      0x01681cf1 sigabrt_signal_handler + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x309cf7ed _sigtramp + 48
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x309c520f pthread_kill + 54
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x309be29f abort + 94
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x367cef6b abort_message + 46
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x367cc34d _ZL17default_terminatev + 24
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3414036f _objc_terminate + 170
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x367cc3c5 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x367cc451 _ZdlPv + 0
10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x367cd79f __cxa_throw + 122
11  RedLaserSample                      0x00040565 _ZN5zxing6qrcode19FinderPatternFinder18selectBestPatternsEv + 172
12  RedLaserSample                      0x000416a5 _ZN5zxing6qrcode19FinderPatternFinder4findERKNS_11DecodeHintsE + 512
13  RedLaserSample                      0x0003a8b3 _ZN5zxing6qrcode8Detector6detectERKNS_11DecodeHintsE + 366
14  RedLaserSample                      0x00046c53 _ZN5zxing6qrcode12QRCodeReader6decodeENS_3RefINS_12BinaryBitmapEEENS_11DecodeHintsE + 130
15  RedLaserSample                      0x0004edcb _ZN5zxing6Reader6decodeENS_3RefINS_12BinaryBitmapEEE + 458
16  RedLaserSample                      0x00055be9 -[FormatReader decode:] + 116
17  RedLaserSample                      0x00013749 -[ZXingDecoder findCodesInBitmap:bytesPerRow:width:height:] + 656
18  RedLaserSample                      0x0005b6df -[BarcodePhotoEngine zxingFindBarcodesInPixmap:] + 222
19  RedLaserSample                      0x00053551 __38-[BarcodeEngine findBarcodesInPixMap:]_block_invoke_066 + 76
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x35737c59 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x35742cab _dispatch_queue_drain + 274
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x35742b19 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 36
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3574378b _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 214
24  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x30980dfb _pthread_wqthread + 294
25  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x30980cd0 start_wqthread + 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current SDK, version 3.3, there is an issue with QR Codes. When the app starts, click the QR code button and it says no. It scans normal now.