# RedLaser Sample App (MonoTouch) closes with no exception when it loads BarcodePickerController

Tags: .net, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am developing an application where I need to scan few barcodes in an ios App. I was asked to used RedLaser library with my monotouch application.

I am able to compile, build, and run the application on my machine after few tweaks.

However once I click on the Scan button from the Home Screen, the application crashes. I cannot see any exception, Errors, or warnings on the Application Output panel on MonoDevelop. I could not find any Log either. The application is running on the iOSSimulator.

The issue happens when the OverrlayController tries to load the ParentPicker. Even just checking its value crashes the application.

I have put a sample of the code where it is crashing. I found that there was an issue with QRCode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319553/monotouch-redlaser-sdk-object), so I disabled QRScanning. but still the same crash. 
I am using

Monotouch 6.0, 
MonoDevelop 3.0.5, 
RedLaser 3.4.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class RLSampleViewController : UIViewController
{
    public RLSampleViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }
    partial void scanPressed (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem sender)
    {
         //THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE APP IS JUST CRASHING 
         if (overlayController.ParentPicker == null)
         {
             BarcodePickerController picker = new BarcodePickerController ();
             // setup picker
             picker.Overlay = overlayController;
             picker.Delegate = new BarcodePickerDelegate (this);
             // Initialize with portrait mode as default
             picker.Orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up;
            // The active scanning region size is set in OverlayController.m
          }

         // The rest of the code was ignored
```

I have updated the question to include the crash log (Thanks to Rolf B. for pointing me to where to find it). However, it still does not make any sense to me as I do not have familiarity with Objective-C.

```
> Process:         RedLaserSample [10999]
> Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone
> Simulator/*/RedLaserSample.app/RedLaserSample
> Identifier:      RedLaserSample
> Version:         ???
> Code Type:       X86 (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [243]
> User ID:         501

> Date/Time:       2013-01-08 16:58:35.532 +1100
> OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
> Report Version:  10

> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
> Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000bf7ffffc

> VM Regions Near 0xbf7ffffc:
>     Stack                  00000000b056d000-00000000b057d000 [   64K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
> --> Stack                  00000000bc000000-00000000bf800000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
>     Stack                  00000000bf800000-00000000c0000000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  

> Application Specific Information:
> iPhone Simulator 358.4, iPhone OS 6.0 (iPhone/10A403)


> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> 0   CoreFoundation                    0x0405f6cd typeStringHash + 13
> 1   CoreFoundation                    0x03fffdb0 __CFDictionaryHashKey + 32
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x03fe53e2 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1426
> 3   CoreFoundation                    0x03fe4e2d CFDictionaryGetValue + 109
> 4   CoreFoundation                    0x0405e0ea +[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:] + 250
> 5   CoreFoundation                    0x040fb5c3 -[NSObject(NSObject)  methodSignatureForSelector:] + 83
> 6   RedLaserSample                    0x0027a752 monotouch_trampoline + 82
> 7   ???                               0x0c7e9010 0 + 209621008
> 8   ???                               0x12c68efc 0 + 315002620
> 9   ???                               0x12c68fd4 0 + 315002836
> 10  RedLaserSample                    0x00077112 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
> 11  RedLaserSample                    0x001d8bae mono_runtime_invoke + 126
> 12  RedLaserSample                    0x0027b568 monotouch_trampoline + 3688
> 13  ???                               0x0c7e9010 0 + 209621008
> 14  ???                               0x12c68efc 0 + 315002620
> 15  ???                               0x12c68fd4 0 + 315002836
```

Comment: Is anything written to the Console or are any crash reports generated? Here is a description of how to get this information: http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-crashes-in-monotouch.html

Comment: Thanks Rolf B., I have updated the question to include the crash report, but it still does not make sense to me. Do you have any idea what this log is telling us??

Comment: Hi Rolf, I have reported the bug in your bugzilla system, It's # 9410. Sorry I could not attach the SampleProject I am using but I put it on dropbox and pasted the link for you. Your help is highly appreciated. 
and just to emphasise, this is the same sample project that is on GitHub monotouch binding page https://github.com/chrisbranson/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/RedLaser/ I just updated the Makefile to generate the RedLaser.dll for their new SDK 3.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the binding (it wasn't prepared for subclassing).

This has now been fixed, and an updated binding is available at http://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

Comment: btw, did you do any other changes other than pumping up the Build # and the version of the SDK, because I did this before, and I was still getting that error!! Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the actual fix for your bug is this commit: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/commit/212c2ec6234b08dfac773d023ab501eef99522d2

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. Thanks again mate, appreciate your help